# Homepage in Navigation

Tags: navigation, craft-features, bootstrap-craft

I've been trying to get the homepage to show up in the navigation...

What I'd like to display is the following...

```
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item active">                                    
    <a class="nav-link" href="/">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">                                    
    <a class="nav-link" href="/schedule">Schedule</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">                                    
    <a class="nav-link" href="/media">Media</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">                                    
    <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The following works to create the last 3 pages, but the homepage (about) does not seem to create.

```
<ul>
  {% set entries = craft.entries.section('page').find() %}
  {% nav navItem in entries %}
  <li class="nav-item{{ navItem.id == entry.id ? ' active' }}">                                    
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ navItem.url }}">{{ navItem.title }}</a>
  </li>
  {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

The following works for a semi-dynamic homepage... however the name does not create... (If they change the title of the homepage on the backend, I'd like it to switch on the front-end.

```
<li class="nav-item{{ craft.request.firstSegment == "" ? ' active' }}">
  <a class="nav-link" href="/">{{ craft.entries.slug('_home_').entry.title }}</a>
</li>
```

Could anyone with a bit more experience with this give me some insight? I'm confused outta my mind.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out how to get this working...See the following..

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('homepage, page').find() %}
{% nav navItem in entries %}
<li class="nav-item{{ navItem.id == entry.id ? ' active' }}">                                    
  <a class="nav-link" href="{{ navItem.uri }}">{{ navItem.title }}</a>
</li>
{% endnav %}
```